# How to style first post differently with 'get_template_part'?

Tags: loop

I need help in styling the first post differently than the rest. What makes this differently is that I'm using this get_template_part in order for infinite scroll to work on my site.

This is what I use on index.php

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile; ?>
```

which will load the loop from content.php. This was my old loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $post = $posts[0]; $c=0;?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $c++; if( !$paged && $c == 1) :?>

<-! first post -->

<?php else :?>

<-! the rest -->

<?php endif;?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work!

```
<?php if ( 1 > get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) { ?>
<?php if ( is_first_post() ) { ?>
    first! <br />
    <?php the_title();?>
    <?php the_excerpt();?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php the_title();?>
<?php the_excerpt();?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt();?>
<?php } ?>
```

You can see it in action - http://openbayou.staging.wpengine.com

Next question I have (same topic) is can this be cleaned up to make it simply as the code underneath is_first_page are duplicates

```
<?php } else { ?>
<?php the_title();?>
<?php the_excerpt();?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_excerpt();?>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `post_class()` in your `content` template like this …

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

… you can filter that and add a special class:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'mark_first_post' );

function mark_first_post( $classes )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $classes[] = 'first-post';
    return $classes;
}
```

Your first post in a loop will now have the class `first-post`. The nice thing is: this filter will run just one time and deactivate itself then.

You can also use another helper function:

```
function is_first_post()
{
    static $called = FALSE;

    if ( ! $called )
    {
        $called = TRUE;
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

You can test for the first post then in your template:

```
if ( is_first_post() )
{
    // render the first post
}
else
{
    // the other posts
}
```

Comment: Will this work if I use the 'if' statement?

     <php if {
     link post
     <?php } elseif { ?>
     aside

I'm asking because the first post will have a large image while the rest will use the thumbnail.

Comment: @GregorySchultz Hm, in this case you need another way. See my update with an alternative.

Comment: First page: `if ( 2 > get_query_var( 'paged' ) )`